# My own malloc() function in C

Tags: algorithm, c, memory-management

Is this acceptable? What is the next step to improve algorithm and make them more clear and faster?

```
typedef struct heap_block
{  
    struct heap_block* next;
    size_t size;
    bool isfree;
    int x; // for alligment
}header;

#define Heap_Capacity 16777216
unsigned long long active_size;  // # bytes in active allocations

static uint64_t heap[Heap_Capacity/sizeof(uint64_t)];

static char* max_heap =(char*)(&heap[0]);
static char* min_heap = (char*)(&heap[0]);
static char *END_CHK = "\xDE\xAD\xC0\xDA";
header* last_allocated;

void* malloc(size_t sz) 
{
    if(sz == 0 || sz > Heap_Capacity)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    header* block = (header*)heap;
    if(active_size == 0)
    {
        set_data_to_block(block, sz);
        return (void*)last_allocated;
    }

    while(block->next != NULL)
    {
        block = block->next;
    }

    block->next = (header*)((char*)to_end_data(block) + 8);
    header* new_block = block->next;
    set_data_to_block(new_block, sz);

    return (void*)last_allocated;
}


void set_data_to_block(header* block, size_t sz)
{
    block->size = sz;
    block->isfree = false;
    block->next = NULL;

    active_size += sz;
    last_allocated = block + 1;
    char* end_of_data_block = (char*)to_end_data(block);

    if(max_heap < end_of_data_block)
    {
        max_heap = end_of_data_block;
    }
    strcpy(end_of_data_block, END_CHK);
}

header* to_start_metadata(header* block)
{
    return --block;
}

header* to_end_data(header* block)
{
    return (header*)((size_t)(block+1) + block->size);
}
```

Comment: if you have malloc you should also have free

Comment: There are a number of undefined variables, such as `last_allocated` and `active_size` and `Heap_Capacity`.  Maybe you should repost the complete code.

Comment: @ivan_petrushenko: still incomplete.  Missing `active_size`, `fail_count`, `fail_size`, `file`, `line`...

Comment: @Edward Now its ok

Comment: @ivan_petrushenko: the code appears to be broken.  Set `Heap_Capacity` to 256 and then try allocating three 100-byte blocks.

Comment: @Edward Thanks! Forgot to add additoanl check `sz > (Heap_Capacity - (size_t)active_size) {return NULL}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23340/discussion-between-ivan-petrushenko-and-edward).

Comment: "What is the next step to improve algorithm and make them more clear and faster?" - this depends on your application. Where do you plan to use it? Also, a simple testing code would be useful.

Comment: It should also be pointed out that the code is highly susceptible to stack overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`struct heap_block` is three words long. This means that if the caller is allocating small objects (one word long or shorter) then your [internal fragmentation](http://www.memorymanagement.org/glossary/i.html#term-internal-fragmentation) will 75% or larger.

The usual way to implement this kind of heap allocation is to store only the *size* of the block in the header. This works because:

1. You only need to keep track of the [free blocks](http://www.memorymanagement.org/glossary/f.html#term-free-block-chain) (because the caller has to keep track of the allocated blocks). So you don't need the `isfree` Boolean: if you know about a block, then it must be free.
2. You only need to store a pointer to the next block when the block is free. But in this case you have the whole of the block available (not just the header) so you can store the pointer in the remainder of the block, overwriting the data that the caller had previously stored there.

Answer (score 7):

- **Avoid globals**

  `last_allocated` is only used to communicate the result of `set_data_to_block` back to `malloc`. *Returning* the result is much cleaner.
- **Avoid special cases**

  There is no need to special case the initial allocation. If you do not want to rely on `((header *) heap)->next == NULL` initially, you may want to provide an initialization method (which I recommend anyway).

Answer (score 3):

### <strike>Empty mallocs</strike>

> ```
>     if(sz == 0 || sz > Heap_Capacity)
> ```

<strike>It is actually legal to call the standard library's `malloc()` with an argument of 0, and you are guaranteed to get a unique pointer when you do (you can't do anything with it though).</strike>

### <strike>Const-correctness</strike>

> ```
> static char *END_CHK = "\xDE\xAD\xC0\xDA";
> ```

<strike>You mean `static char const *` right? String literals are `char const *` not `char *` (though the compiler won't warn you about it)</strike>

### <strike>Uninitialized variables</strike>

<strike>`active_size` is still uninitialized at the time of first access. Didn't the compiler warn you about this?</strike>

### Data types

Why is `heap` defined as being a `uint64_t []`, but then always accessed by casting to a `char *`, and sometimes a `header *`?

### Out of bounds

if the heap is almost full, you check to see if there's enough space for the header and the requested memory...and then you write 5 extra bytes after that. You could end up writing past the bounds of `heap`.

### Running time

> ```
> while(block->next != NULL)
> {
>     block = block->next;
> }
> ```

The more memory you allocate, the longer and longer each `malloc` will take. You need a better data structure.

Comment: In C, global variables are initialized to 0 if no initializer is given. (It's still a good idea to write an explicit initializer, to make it clear what happens.)

Comment: "argument of 0... guaranteed to get a unique pointer when you do" is incorrect.  `malloc(0)` may return `NULL` even with multiple calls of `malloc(0)`. Not even certain uniqueness holds here either.   "If the size of the space requested is zero, the behavior is implementation-defined: either a null pointer is returned, or the behavior is as if the size were some nonzero value, except that the returned pointer shall not be used to access an object." C11 §7.22.3 1

Comment: Wow, that's not how I remembered it used to be. C11's way makes a lot mroe sense.Thanks.

Comment: The type of a string literal in C is still `char*` and not `const char*`. Although it is undefined behavior to modify it, it is still defined by standards to be `char*`.

Comment: @Ajay While `char *s = "literal"` is legal, a good compiler will warn about it.  Using a pointer to `const char` will make the code safer and silence the warning.

Answer (score 3):

One additional comment on top of what's already mentioned in previous answers.

---

Using `sizeof(void*)` instead of `8` will make it:

1. More efficient (memory wise) on 32-bit platforms
2. More robust on future ("larger than 64-bit") platforms